# Zbar on raspberry?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, zbar, image-scanner

I'm trying use zbar on RPI3 but i have a problem. I dont have ImageScanner, Image... module.

```
import zbar
scanner = zbar.ImageScanner() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ImageScanner'
```

I tried to install it from pip, official repository, some fork, but nothing work.

```
https://pastebin.com/ajbWdSct
```

how can i access image modul?

Comment: do you ahve the correct library? sometimes they have different names than to what you think

Comment: Please do not post code/errors to pastebin, include information actually in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To list module content try to type:

```
import zbar
dir(zbar)
```

See example are in source https://github.com/npinchot/zbar/blob/master/examples/read_one.py

Comment: >>> dir(zbar)
['Scanner', 'Symbol', 'ZBAR_CONFIGS', 'ZBAR_SYMBOLS', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'zbar']

Comment: The example isn't working.   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Processor'